# Getting prefer-arrow-callback with Node https

Tags: node.js, eslint

I saw the the `request` library was depreciated, so I have been trying to switch to Node's `https` method instead. I pieced together this basic request function so far.

```
const https = require('https')

function httpRequest(options) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const serverRequest = https.request(options, response => {
      let body = ''

      response.on('data', function (d) {
        body += d
      });

      response.on('end', function () {
        resolve(JSON.parse(body))
      })
    })

    serverRequest.on('error', err => {
      reject(err)
    })

    serverRequest.end()
  })
}
```

It works, but causes eslint to throw `prefer-arrow-callback`. I don't fully understand why https uses the `.on` syntax in the first place, so I'm wondering if this function can be re-written in a way that gets rid of the warning and is more in line with modern JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that that error means to say it would prefer a Lambda function definition. If you are new to lambda functions, they are formatted as such:

```js
(parameters) => {

}
```

Try re-writing your code like this:

```js
response.on('data', (d) => {
   body += d;
});
response.on('end', () => {
   resolve(JSON.parse(body));
});
```

As for the use of `.on`, its just how Node formats event listeners.